# Maven basically can't read any resolution tracking file

Tags: maven

Recently (this morning) I stumbled across the following problem :
Jenkins build on one of my projects was failing.

I tried to make it work locally on my machine and was quite pleased (yet scared) to see it build seamlessly.

I, then, logged back to the jenkins machine to try to manually launch the `mvn clean install` and discovered that cute little error all over my build log.

```
[WARNING] Failed to read resolution tracking file /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/local/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/_maven.repositories
java.io.IOException: Aucun verrou disponible
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:90)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:1021)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.TrackingFileManager.lock(TrackingFileManager.java:203)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.TrackingFileManager.read(TrackingFileManager.java:58)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager.readRepos(EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager.java:144)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager.find(EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager.java:69)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:307)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Unfortunately I don't have the faintest idea of the reason why I get this.
My internet researches so far suggest that would be related to `NFS` somehow but :

- I don't know the first thing on NFS
- The person that could answer on the subject of the jenkins machine configuration is not anywhare around (and isn't likely to be anytime soon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5629
which is unresolved as at 2015-01-06.  :(
Encounter this with the versions-maven-plugin also.

Comment: Update: Working with Jenkins 1.598, Maven plugin 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI...  I encountered similar issues when trying to build Maven Eclipse project (even when doing just the basic "Run As Maven Clean").  This seems to related to my U:\drive and the VPN....  I encountered the above problem when working from home using VPN access (ps. I can open up any files on my U: drive no problem).  When I am working inside my company, then the problem doesn't come up.

My environment:
Windows 7 64bit
Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 
  with Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.2.20150902 
U:\Profile.m2\settings.xml   (my Maven settings.xml file is on local drive).

I installed Maven (3.3.9) and ran mvn clean successfully on the command line.  This is consistently no matter even when I worked from home with the VPN access.